# JSON formatting for Ember

Tags: json, ember.js

In Ember.js, I have a page that returns AJAX, formatted as:

```
{
    "foo": [
        {
            "foo1": "1",
            "foo2": "2"
        }
    ],
    "bar": [
        {
            "bar1": "1",
            "bar2": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is loaded by:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return jQuery.post('http://url/ajax', {
            s: params.query,
        }, function(){}, 'json');
    }
});
```

But Ember throws the errors (even with a static-content only template):

```
Error while processing route: posts undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
at m.extend._setupArrangedContent (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.6.0/ember.min.js:13:29556)
at ...

TypeError: undefined is not a function
at m.extend._setupArrangedContent (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.6.0/ember.min.js:13:29556)
at ...
```

If nothing is returned, the static-content only template loads. This leads me to believe the error is in the JSON formatting, but the JSON works in http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Comment: What do "foo1" and "foo2" represent? Should that be "id" in both cases?

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example as jsbin? The PostsRoute looks fine to me.

Comment: Try this return jQuery.post('http://url/ajax', {
            s: params.query,
        }).then(function(response){return response;});

Answer (score 1):

While creating a jsbin of the problem, I found the ArrayController of Posts was causing the problem - Ember must have been expecting an array of elements, and giving it a non-array model was causing the error.